# Casting of type struct to memory location of a fixed sized array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, struct

I am a little confused as to what it means to cast a type struct to some memory location in a fixed size array and then wanting to access a specific memory location within the range used for the struct. For example:

```
static char arraymemory[100];

struct header{ 
sruct header *previous, *successor; 
int isfree; 
int size; 
};

struct header *headerptr;

headerptr= (struct header*)((char*)p + sizeof(struct header));
```

where p is a pointer of type struct header that points to the beginning of the array and sizeof(struct header) is the byte count of the struct itself plus the members.

So i checked and sizeof(struct header) is 24 bytes. Now i have an array of char with 1 byte each, so 1 * 100=size of array. I take the pointer p that is located at the beginning of the array and move it 24 bytes(whatever that memory location is), that is what headerptr will point to. If i declare headerptr->isfree and headerptr->size equal to something along with having the pointers previous and successor hold a memory location, does that mean that from where headerptr points to up to at most 24 bytes after will be used for the struct and its members?

Second question, assuming the answer to the above is yes, what happens if i end up accessing the memory location of headerptr + 3? It would be easy to see the output if a plain char data type value such as 'a' was at that specific memory location because headerptr +2 or headerptr +3 would give you a 1 byte char to read. But how does it work if you used that entire range for a struct and you access a specific memory location of that set. Would you get access to one of the members of the struct? Some types take more than 1 byte(char), like int which takes 4. Assuming member isfree is the first thing declared in the struct and it is the first thing that headerptr points to, what does reading the data inside the memory of headerptr + 3 give? The value of isfree regardless of where in the 4 bytes we point to? It is hard for me to visualize this because when i picture the char array i just think of 1 cell for each characters. If we have a struct with multiple different data type that take up multiple cells for each members of the struct and we point to a specific cell, what do we get?

Comment: This fragment exhibits undefined behaviour because alignment requirements of `struct header` may be greater than that of `char`.

Comment: Instead of doing this `headerptr= (struct header*)((char*)p + sizeof(struct header));` you can simply do `headerptr = p + 1;` since type of `p` is `struct header*`.

Comment: @n.m., could you elaborate?

Comment: @n.m., are you saying i may get undefined behavior because headerptr+3 might access memory reserved for the padding of the struct? If so this was just an example. I am asking about what happens when i access a headerptr + a certain byte count of the array. If isfree takes up 4 bytes and headerptr + x is part of isfree, do i access the value of isfree regardless of whether it is the first, second, third, of fourth byte? do they all share the same memory location?

Comment: You cannot cast pointer to less-aligned type (char) to pointer to more-aligned type (someothertype). This is not allowed by the standard. There's an exception for casting `someothertype*` to `void*` and back to `someothertype*` but you are not doing this.

Comment: No, padding is irrelevant. You are violating alignment requirements.

Comment: The answer to that I think is undefined. Some compilers may round your the pointer down the nearest alignment (subtracting the 3), some may subtract 2 (if they are 16bit alignment), some may subtract nothing. So when you access isfree you may be accessing the wrong memory. Thats all that can really be said as the actual make up of a struct is implementation dependent. Why don't you try it? Set the value some known numbers, then set the headerptr to that spot plus 3 bytes and print then numbers out. THen try it on a 8bit system. Then a 16bit system. It will be up to the system you run it on.

Comment: @n.m., not sure i understand what you are saying, i dont get any errors in the program that does this. Pointer p is of struct header to begin with, i am simply casting it as a char pointer to move through the array x*1 byte at a time. In this case x is 24 bytes. I am then taking the result and casting it back to a struct header because that is the type that headerptr is. Are you saying this is wrong...?

Comment: It is advisable to look up what "undefined behaviour" means, and also what "alignment" means. These concepts are important to anyone who writes C.

Comment: @n.m., Okay i've looked up alignment and undefined behavior. You said padding is irrelevant but isn't alignment insured by using padding? In the case of my question if i do not access padding within the struct but one of the 4 bytes of isfree by doing headerptr + 3, what would the value of the memory accessed(headerptr+3) be if isfree=101; ?

Comment: Padding is used to ensure alignment within a struct, but alignment exists independently of padding (or structs). `int` has alignment, but no padding. You can replace your struct with an `int` and the entire argument still holds.

Comment: @n.m. so alignment is bounding the memory location of in this case an int to 4 bytes. Because it is 4 bytes it does not need padding Is this correct? If so would accessing headerptr+3, where headerptr+3 could be the first, second, third or fourth byte of the int isfree, still give the resulting value of 101 because each byte is bounded to the same memory address?

Comment: In most cases alignment is manifested as address divisibility. For example, on many platforms an address of an `int` must be a multiple of 4. If you try to dereference an `int` pointer which is an odd number the program will get a fatal runtime error. An address of `char` has no divisibility requirements. So if the compiler allocates `arraymemory` at an odd address,  which it perfectly allowed to, any access to `int` through a pointer to `arraymemory` will simply fail on these platforms. Though giving an incorrect result on other platforms is definitely possible too.

Comment: @n.m. so each byte that makes up int isfree would have its own memory address? If so then i'm trying to wrap my head around how these addresses form together so that when you access isfree at the right memory location of the 4 bytes(assuming the beginning?) it works to print correctly...

Comment: Yes each byte has its own address.

Comment: how do each byte work together when dealing with an int? Is there maybe a diagram/picture or reference you could point me to? I feel like i'm asking a lot of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are only meaningful provided that `p` is sufficiently aligned, which is not guaranteed if `p` points to the beginning of a `char` array, so let's assume `struct header *p = malloc(100);` (the pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned for any type).

But first, there's this strange wording in your post:

> sizeof(struct header) is the byte count of the struct itself plus the
>   members.

The *struct itself* already contains its members, so the *plus the members* doesn't make sense.

> If i declare headerptr->isfree and headerptr->size equal to something
>   along with having the pointers previous and successor hold a memory
>   location, does that mean that from where headerptr points to up to at
>   most 24 bytes after will be used for the struct and its members?

To be exact, it will be the byte headerptr points to through 23 bytes after, totalling 24 bytes.

> what happens if i end up accessing the memory location of headerptr +
>   3?

Since `headerptr` is of type `struct header *` and 24 bytes from the start of the allocated memory, `headerptr + 3` is 72 bytes after, i. e. 96 bytes from the start. Now what happens depends on how you access that location.

> It would be easy to see the output if a plain char data type value
>   such as 'a' was at that specific memory location because headerptr +2
>   or headerptr +3 would give you a 1 byte char to read. But how does it
>   work if you used that entire range for a struct and you access a
>   specific memory location of that set. Would you get access to one of
>   the members of the struct?

When you write `headerptr +3`, you seem to mean `(char *)headerptr + 3`; I'll assume that from here on. Also, access of individual bytes of an object of a size greater than 1 is only safe with the type `unsigned char`. That way we would get access to one byte of one of the struct members.

> Assuming member isfree is the first thing declared in the struct and
>   it is the first thing that headerptr points to, what does reading the
>   data inside the memory of headerptr + 3 give?

`((unsigned char *)headerptr)[3]` then yields the value of the fourth byte of `isfree`, provided that `sizeof isfree` is at least 4.

> If we have a struct with multiple different data type that take up
>   multiple cells for each members of the struct and we point to a
>   specific cell, what do we get?

We get what we ask for - one byte or cell or (single-byte) character, as in the above example.